# __getattr__ of meta class not being called

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the title says. It seems no matter what I do, `__getattr__` will not be called. I also tried it for instance (absurd, I know), with predictably no response. As if `__getattr__` was banned in meta classes.

I'd appreciate any pointer to documentation about this.

The code:

```
class PreinsertMeta(type):

    def resolvedField(self):
        if isinstance(self.field, basestring):
            tbl, fld = self.field.split(".")
            self.field = (tbl, fld)
        return self.field

    Field = property(resolvedField)

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == "field":
            if isinstance(self.field, basestring):
                tbl, fld = self.field.split(".")
                self.field = (tbl, fld)
            return self.field
        else:
            return super(PreinsertMeta, self).__getattr__(attrname)

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        super(PreinsertMeta, self).__setattr__(attrname, value)


class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = PreinsertMeta
    field = "test.field"

print Test.field  # Should already print the tuple
Test.field = "another.field"  # __setattr__ gets called nicely
print Test.field  # Again with the string?
print Test.Field  # note the capital 'F', this actually calls resolvedField() and prints the tuple
```

Thanks to BrenBarn, here's the final working implementation:

```
class PreinsertMeta(type):

    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == "field" and isinstance(object.__getattribute__(self, attrname), basestring):
            tbl, fld = object.__getattribute__(self, attrname).split(".")
            self.field = (tbl, fld)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access), `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute does not exist.  Since your class has a `field` attribute, that blocks `__getattr__`.  You can use `__getattribute__` if you really want to intercept all attribute access, although it's not clear from your example why you need to do this.  Note that this has nothing to do with metaclasses; you would see the same behavior if you created an instance of an ordinary class and gave it some attribute.

Even assuming you used `__getattribute__`, so it was called when the attribute exists, your implementation doesn't make much sense.  Inside `__getattr__` you try to get a value for `self.field`.  But if `__getattribute__` was called in the first place, it will be called again for this access, creating an infinite recursion: in order to get `self.field`, it has to call `__getattribute__`, which again tries to get `self.field`, which again calls `__getattribute__`, etc.  See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) for `__getattribute__` for how to get around this.

Comment: Thank you, forgot there's `__getattribute__` as well :)  And about the sense of it all: the above implementation is for a subclass of a parent class where the `field` member cannot reference base class member directly as it doesn't exist at the time. The __getattribute__ version allows me to use the resolved member variable at the time of use. Since neither the enclosing nor subclass are ever instanced, I try to work this with meta classes.